# I want to use function sort in python 3.7.4 but I can't. Why?

Tags: python, list, sorting

In python 3.7.4 I wnat to sort the array but I can't. I used the function sort and wrote this code -

```
arr = [0,5,8,9,6,3,1,2]
print(arr.sort())
```

output

```
None
```

Please help me.

Comment: `.sort()` is an in-place method, means it sorts the list (and the list is modified) and returns NoneType. Try `print(arr)` to see the sorted list.

Comment: `print(sorted(arr))` will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Python's `list.sort()` modifies the list in-place and does not return it. For example:

```
x = [0,5,8,9,6,3,1,2]
print(x)  # [0, 5, 8, 9, 6, 3, 1, 2]

x.sort()
print(x)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for more information on `list` methods.